# Jquery click events on dynamic element doesnt work with variable

Tags: jquery

```
function srclist(objs){
    $('.searchnode').children().remove()
    $('.subnode').children().remove()    
    if(objs.length>0){

        for(i=0;i<objs.length;i++){
            $('<div name="'+objs[i]._id+'"class="srcoption">'+objs[i].title+'</div>').appendTo('.searchnode')
        }

        $('.searchnode').on('click','div.srcoption',()=>{
           console.log($(this).name)
        })
    }
}
```

console.log($(this).name) this is not working

console.log('hello ')-> this is working well

i need to take dynamic elements name thx for ur help

Comment: Also you should use `$(this).attr('name')` instead if you want to get `name` attribute

Comment: @Mohammad or just `this.name`

Comment: $('.searchnode').on('click','div.srcoption',function(){
            console.log($(this).attr('name'))
        }) THIS IS WORKED THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using the arrow function for your click events callback.

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not have its own this... ([Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions))

```
$('.searchnode').on('click','div.srcoption',function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('name'))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an arrow function there. Arrow functions do not bind the this to the function. Change that to a normal function and it will work fine.

```
    $('.searchnode').on('click','div.srcoption',function(){
       console.log($(this).attr('name'))
    })
```

Ref. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not have its own this, arguments, super, or new.target. These function expressions are best suited for non-method functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

```js
var objs = [
  { _id: '1', title: 'Title 1' }
  , { _id: '2', title: 'Title 2' }
];

for (i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
  $('<div name="' + objs[i]._id + '"class="srcoption">' + objs[i].title + '</div>').appendTo('.searchnode')
}

$('.searchnode').on('click', 'div.srcoption', function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('name'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="searchnode"></div>
```

Comment: @SeyitUmutBicer updated.  It seems name is not exposed as a property.

Answer (score 0):

in this line

```
$('<div name="' + objs[i]._id + '"class="srcoption">' + objs[i].title + '</div>').appendTo('.searchnode')
```

there should be one space after name

```
$('<div name="' + objs[i]._id + '" class="srcoption">' + objs[i].title + '</div>').appendTo('.searchnode')
```

instead of

```
$('.searchnode').on('click','div.srcoption',()=>{
           console.log($(this).name)
})
```

you can directly target to "srcoption" class

```
 var container=$('.searchnode');
 for(i=0;i<objs.length;i++){
            var _div=$("<div/>",{
               id:objs[i]._id,
               class: "srcoption", 
               text:objs[i].title   
            })
            _div.attr("name",objs[i]._id);
            container.append(_div);
        }
  $('.srcoption').on('click',function(){
               console.log($(this).attr('name'))
    });
```

Comment: You should use `$(this).attr('name')` or `this.name`

Comment: can you try this ? @SeyitUmutBicer